# Simplifying $\frac{-8+\sqrt{48}}{8}$ to $\frac{-2+\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I cannot understand the logic of getting from "unsimplified" to "simplified":

> An unsimplified answer: $x=\dfrac{-8+\sqrt{48}}{8}$, $\dfrac{-8-\sqrt{48}}{8}$
>
> A simplified answer: $x=\dfrac{-2+\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $\dfrac{-2-\sqrt{3}}{2}$

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyzsh.png))

Would someone please explain? Thank you.

Comment: There is no square root in the denominator in your image (as you claim in your title).  What you can do is factor out $4 = \sqrt{16}.$

Comment: $\sqrt{48} = \sqrt{3\cdot 16}$, in the numerator, and then you cancel. But your title is not related to your question.

Comment: thanks, fixed title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{-8\pm\sqrt{48}}{8}=\frac{-8\pm\sqrt{16}\cdot\sqrt{3}}{8}=\frac{-8\pm4\sqrt{3}}{8}=\frac{4(-2\pm\sqrt{3})}{4\cdot 2}=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Simplification

Comment: Sorry, haven't taken math in a long time...so I apologize if this is obvious, but I understand up to the 3rd step, but the last step you canceled out the radical coefficient (4) with the denominator (8), leaving a 2, but what about the -8, how did that get reduced to a -2?

Comment: divide top and bottom by 4

Comment: Ahhh, thank you for updating the answer for me, it is more clear now. Thank you!